# Differentiate without using chain rule in 5 steps

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm facing problem with this challenge problem. Evaluate

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\left(x\sin x+\cos x\right)}{\left(x\sin x-\cos x\right)^2}$ without using chain rule and using the basic differentiation rules in 5 steps.

Comment: What problems have you faced while trying this? What basic differentiation rules do you know?

Comment: It appears to be a lot hairy and difficult to simply using product and quotient rules.

Comment: It's really not so bad if you just do it slowly and properly. The point is that you have to show where you get stuck, not ask others to do it for you.

Comment: That is what I'm not able to make out, I've expanded all the terms but at the end I reach a point where no further simplification is possible and I don't get the desired answer.

Comment: Write it down here, then perhaps somebody can help.

Comment: What would be the solution with chain rule?

Comment: can we use the quotient rule?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner See OP's second comment; I would think so.

Comment: I don't see why this can't be done in ONE step without the chain rule. You have $y = \frac{A(x)}{B(x)\cdot B(x)},$ so $y' = \frac{A'BB\; - \; A(BB' + B'B)}{(BB)^2},$ where expressions for $A,$ $B,$ $A',$ and $B'$ in terms of $x,$ $\sin x,$ and $\cos x$ are written down as you write this out. Here I'm only using the $A$'s and $B$'s as abbreviations in explaining what one does. If this violates anything, then I think you need to explain exactly what constitutes "a step".

Answer (score 1):

the quotient rule is given by
$$\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$
given $$u=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$
$$v=?(x\sin(x)-\cos(x))^2$$ then we get
$$u'=\sin(x)+x\cos(x)-\sin(x)=x\cos(x)$$
$$v'=2(x\sin(x)-\cos(x))(\sin(x)+x\cos(x)+\sin(x))$$
can you proceed?